# Nested json object binding to sap ui5 table

Tags: json, sapui5

I have a JSON object as below:

```
{
"Routes": 
{
"A":
[
{"Locality": "L1","Pickup": "Junction1","Time": "6:45AM"},
{"Locality": "L2","Pickup": "Junction2","Time": "6:48Am"},
{"Locality": "L3","Pickup": "Junction3","Time": "6:50AM"},
{"Locality": "L4","Pickup": "Junction4","Time": "6:55AM"},
{"Locality": "L5","Pickup": "Junction5","Time": "6:58AM"},
{"Locality": "L6","Pickup": "Junction6","Time": "7:00AM"}
]
,

"A1":
[
{"Locality": "K1","Pickup": "Junction1","Time": "6:45AM"},
{"Locality": "K2","Pickup": "Junction2","Time": "6:48Am"},
{"Locality": "K3","Pickup": "Junction3","Time": "6:50AM"},
{"Locality": "K4","Pickup": "Junction4","Time": "6:55AM"},
{"Locality": "K5","Pickup": "Junction5","Time": "6:58AM"},
{"Locality": "K6","Pickup": "Junction6","Time": "7:00AM"}
]
}
}
```

and setting the model to UI5 view as below in controller init function.

```
var oModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/routes.json");
this.getView().setModel(oModel1,"tablemodel");
```

The JSON model is stored in a model folder as shown above.

In view I have declared a table.

How can I bind all the "A1" routes present in JSON file to the table. I am confused giving the path to the table to bind rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/routes.json");
oTable.setModel(oModel);
oTable.bindRows("/Routes/A1");
```

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/6qbe2Lgs/1/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: can we use the model which is set to the view  for table (oTable ) with out setting the model explicitly to table?

Comment: Yes its working, but its not working for named model so in that case for named model binded to view, is it mandatory to bind the model to table ?

Comment: for named model, you need to change the binding path to : "tablemodel>/Routes/A1".. And for properties too it will be "{tablemodel>Locality}"

Comment: can you elaborate the same i am not able to get the result with named model. that is the binding model to view and bind properties of table to named model of view?